# Is there any free network drive/share benchmark tool for Windows?

Tags: networking, performance, samba, benchmarking, smb

I want to know if there is any free tool to test the performance of a smb/CIFS network share. All free speed test I saw were for local drives only.

Comment: Please move this question to ServerFault

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There certainly is, it is called iPerf and it works pretty well. Only used the windows version on NT shares but there is a linux version too and you can test speed between one installed on the client (windows) and another installed on Linux (server)

Get it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/)

Comment: It doesn't look like the thing I'm looking for. This one can generate traffic on any port and this is not what I was looking for. It's not about the network speed - it about the speed of the file server.